# What is the formula for lognormal hazard?

Tags: survival, lognormal-distribution, parameterization

I'm plotting a bunch of survivor and hazard curves.

The lognormal survivor function is:

$S(t)=1-\Phi(\frac{log(t)-\mu}{\sigma}) $

Where $\mu$ is the scalar parameter.

From a website (http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3669.htm), the null model gives a hazard function of:

$h(t,σ)=\frac{\frac{1}{tσ}ϕ(\frac{\ln t}{\sigma})}{Φ(\frac{−\ln t}{\sigma})}$

where ϕ is the probability density function of the normal distribution and Φ is the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution.

Where does the scale parameter come in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If
$$
S(t) = 1 - \Phi \left( \frac{\log(t) - \mu}{\sigma} \right)
$$
then
$$
f(t) = -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}S(t) = \frac{\phi \left( \frac{\log(t) - \mu}{\sigma} \right)}{\sigma t}
$$
(as $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Phi(\cdot) = \phi(\cdot)$) and 
$$
h(t) = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)} = \frac{\phi \left( \frac{\log(t) - \mu}{\sigma} \right)}{\sigma t \left[1 - \Phi \left( \frac{\log(t) - \mu}{\sigma} \right)\right]}
$$

Replacing $\mu$ by $0$ in the above formula (what is referred to as the "null model" in your question), leads to
$$
h(t) =  \frac{\phi \left( \frac{\log(t)}{\sigma} \right)}{\sigma t \left[1 - \Phi \left( \frac{\log(t)}{\sigma} \right)\right]}
$$
which is the same as what you give as
$$
\Phi(-x) = 1 - \Phi(x)
$$

Comment: Is the hazard function I wrote also a correct derivation of the null survivor function (with -mu removed)? The two derivations seem a bit different; particularly the 1-Phi part.

Comment: I have edited my post to answer this